# MySQLi binding parameters in a prepared statement doesn't work unless inserted after "WHERE"

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have some PHP code that pulls info from a database. It uses a prepared statement, which works fine as written below:

```
<?php

$n = '5';

if ($stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT Title FROM Items WHERE ID = ?"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $n);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($title);
    while ($stmt->fetch())
    {
        echo $title;
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

And let's say this will echo "Batman".

However, when I move the placeholder to here:

```
"SELECT ? FROM Items WHERE ID = 5"
```

And change:

```
$n = 'Title';
```

Instead of echoing "Batman", it echoes "Title". Is it not possible to use a placeholder as a SELECT parameter?

Comment: `Is it not possible to use a placeholder as a SELECT parameter?` yes its not possible yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is this:

```
SELECT "Title" FROM Items WHERE ID = 5
```

You cant use prepared statement bindings for identifiers, only for parameters.

Comment: OK, thank you. So I'll have to write different queries if I want to select different columns while keeping the filter the same?

Comment: *Why* do you want different columns?

Comment: @chazbot7 You can write a query to select multiple columns at once.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I am actually trying to have a placeholder in both spots. Different rows have different categories, and based on the category, I want to select different columns. But, I can now see that for my purposes, just having different queries would be much easier.

Comment: @datasage Yes, what I was looking at was this: If the category is A, then I want to select columns 2, 5, and 7. If the category is B, I want columns 4, 5, and 8. Or would it be easier to just select them all regardless of the category, and only use the information I want?

Comment: @chazbot7 your database apparently require different design

Comment: @YourCommonSense My application isn't that large, so I figured multiple tables for each category wouldn't be needed. But yes, you're correct, there should be a table for each one. I'm just trying to work with what's already in place without redesigning the whole thing.

Comment: @chazbot7 no-no! Not a table for each category! One table but categories have to be stored in rows, not columns!

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have a column named "Category" and each row is assigned one. The query selects additional columns based on what is inside that one. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: @chazbot7 dude. I know no your table structure. So, I cannot come up with ready made database plan. I can only judge by indirect hints like selecting fields in staggered rows. Which is sure sign of a bad structure. Such selection have to be done from rows, not columns.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Sorry, I was just trying to clarify what you were saying, not asking for a plan or anything. Thank you for your help, it's very much appreciated. I've got it figured out to where it works just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works this way.
Prepared statements supposed for data, not for arbitrary query part.

So, you cannot use placeholders for identifiers with raw mysqli. However, you can do it with [safemysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql):

```
$field = $db->getOne("SELECT ?n FROM Items WHERE ID = 5", 'Title');
```

But if you really need to select one particular field dynamically - there is something wrong with your design.